# What is the point of HID lamps?

Tags: hid

I was reading a discussion about different HID lamps and I was wondering why would you use HID lamps in the first place?
Is it for fuel/energy efficiency?
Is it for their higher brightness?
Color of light?

They cost quit a bit!

EDIT: To make it clear, I don't see why one would spend that much money to replace their headlights with HID lights. I want to know what people usually want to achieve when they do this. Do they want to have brighter more focused lights? or they want to conserve fuel/energy and improve their MPG? or they just want to be cool?
In my opinion this is not an open ended discussion.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Do you have a specific question about a particular application?  At present, this sounds like an open-ended discussion topic that fits squarely under this FAQ topic: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask  Perhaps some additional content to keep this from sounding so open-ended would be in order?

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-intensity_discharge_lamp):

> High-intensity discharge (HID) lamps make more visible light per unit
>   of electric power consumed than fluorescent and incandescent lamps
>   since a greater proportion of their radiation is visible light in
>   contrast to heat.

Comment: They also tend to have a much sharper cutoff, with less light wasted on place you don't need it.

Comment: @Brian we could make this whole post a wiki to capture this sort of info.

Comment: Theoretically they should last longer as well. On my car they are expected to never need replacing during the car's lifespan.